# Where to put Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

As a new student to Java I have bean practicing writing methods and then calling them from a different class. I would like to know how to have the radius determined by user input. I understand I need to use the `Scanner` class but I'm not sure which class to import the `Scanner` in and where to put the following bit of code.

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter radius");
int radius = userInput.nextInt();
```

#### FIRST FILE - My Methods

```
package circle;

public class Circle {
  private double radius;
  final double pi;

  public Circle(double radiusIn, double piIn) {
    radius = radiusIn;
    pi = piIn;
  }

  public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
  }

  public double calculateDiameter() {
    return radius + radius;
  }

  public double calculateCircumference() {
    return 2 * pi * radius;
  }

  public double calculateArea() {
    return pi * radius * radius;
  }
}
```

#### SECOND FILE

```
package circle;

public class CircleTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Circle myCircle;
    myCircle = new Circle(3, 3.14159);
    System.out.println("Circle radius is " + myCircle.getRadius());
    System.out.println("Circle diameter is " + myCircle.calculateDiameter());
    System.out.println("Circle circumference is "
        + myCircle.calculateCircumference());
    System.out.println("Circle area is " + myCircle.calculateArea());
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to put the call into the class that contains the static  main method (this is the classic way).

Comment: Welcome To SO. If you have read basic tutorial on how to write JAVA program than it is easy for you. Its in `main` method in class `CircleTest`.

Comment: Use a "utility class" i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75674577/11211041 or a Singleton class i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29323215/11211041

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you declare variables where you need them in this case that means in the main method where the rest of the user interaction takes place.

```
package circle;

public class CircleTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Circle myCircle;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter radius");
    int radius = userInput.nextInt();

    myCircle = new Circle(radius);
    System.out.println("Circle radius is " + myCircle.getRadius());
    System.out.println("Circle diameter is " + myCircle.calculateDiameter());
    System.out.println("Circle circumference is "
        + myCircle.calculateCircumference());
    System.out.println("Circle area is " + myCircle.calculateArea());
  }
}
```

Also Math.PI is a much more accurate approximation of pi. Use that instead of relying on the user to pass in the correct value:

```
package circle;

public class Circle {
  private double radius;


  public Circle(double radiusIn) {
    radius = radiusIn;
  }

  public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
  }

  public double calculateDiameter() {
    return radius + radius;
  }

  public double calculateCircumference() {
    return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
  }

  public double calculateArea() {
    return Math.PI * radius * radius;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great thank you and thanks also for the heads up on the Math.PI thing. thanks to @durron597

Answer (score 1):

Think of an `Object` as **an object**, like an apple or a toothbrush.

`class Circle` is a defintion of an Object; it's a description that attempts to match reality. The predefined Java `Object` is like anything you might find in reality, you can't call `eat()` on an Object (in the real world) because it might be an apple, but it might be a toothbrush (or a circle).

Therefore, place the code **where it makes sense as if it were a real world object**. You want to retrieve user input. Does a circle know how to read user input? **No!**

You call your other class `CircleTest`. But what it really is, is `CircleCreationApplication`; that might be a better name for it. In an application that creates circles, you would receive user input. So that is where the code can go. Once you have your user input, you can use that to create the circle.

```
package circle;

public class CircleCreationApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Circle myCircle;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter radius");
    int radius = userInput.nextInt();

    myCircle = new Circle(radius, 3.14159);
    System.out.println("Circle radius is " + myCircle.getRadius());
    System.out.println("Circle diameter is " + myCircle.calculateDiameter());
    System.out.println("Circle circumference is "
        + myCircle.calculateCircumference());
    System.out.println("Circle area is " + myCircle.calculateArea());

    userInput.close();
  }
}
```

---

Note: @ratchetfreak's answer has some other good things. Please read that as well

Comment: I think a better name is: "CreateCircle" or maybe just "Main"

Answer (score 0):

I think the user interaction code goes into the main class. That's where you handle the workflow, depending on user input. What you actually want is to remove the hardcoded radius (3) and read the value from the user using the `Scanner`, right?

Then your code snippet goes in the `main` method, right before instantiating the `Circle` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] args)            
{         
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter radius");
    int radius = userInput.nextInt();
    Circle myCircle;
    myCircle = new Circle(radius, 3.14159); 
    System.out.println("Circle radius is " + myCircle.getRadius());
    System.out.println("Circle diameter is " + myCircle.calculateDiameter ());
    System.out.println("Circle circumference is " + myCircle.calculateCircumference());
    System.out.println("Circle area is " + myCircle.calculateArea());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You would want to import the scanner and add the code to the second file. Then you can use `radius` as argument to the Circle constructor instead of just 3.